# Reading columns of strings and integers from file

Tags: c, function, file, struct

I am able to read chars, words, sentences and integers from separate files but I am struggling to read words and integers from the **same** file. Let's say my file contains the following:

```
Patrice 95
Rio 96
Marcus 78
Wayne 69
Alex 67
Chris 100
Nemanja 78
```

My partial solution (to read in strings) so far was to use `fgetc()` and check for spaces and or carriage returns in my text file to separate the name from the number.

The main issue with `fgetc` is that it reads in character by character, and so integers are not meant to be read in like this. As a workaround, I am converting the character to an integer whenever a number is read in.

This is the main code structure:

```
typedef struct person {
    char name[10][10];
    char surname[10][10];
    int age [10];
} person_t;

FILE *inp; /* pointer to input file */
char c;
int word_count = 0;
int char_count = 0;
int i = 0;
int x;
person_t my_person;

while ((c = fgetc(inp)) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\r') {
            printf("\n");

            my_person.name[word_count][char_count] = '\0'; //Terminate the string
            char_count = 0; //Reset the counter.
            word_count++;
        }
        else {

            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                x = c - '0'; //converting to int
                my_person.age[i] = x;
                printf("%d", my_person.age[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else {
                my_person.name[word_count][char_count] = c; 
                printf("%c",my_person.name[word_count][char_count]);

                if (char_count < 19) {
                    char_count++;
                }
                else {
                    char_count = 0;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i<7; i++) {
    printf("ages: %d \n",my_person.age[i] );  //never executes
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Patrice
95

Rio
96

Marcus
78

Wayne
69

Alex
67

Chris
```

Full code can be found on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/9MCr7ng4).

Why is the for loop never executing? Any suggestions on what I can improve to read the columns of strings and integers?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, both very valid points that I was stupidly overseeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fgets()` to read a whole line.

```
char line[100];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, inp)) {
    // got a line, need to isolate parts
}
```

Then, depending on whether the words can have embedded spaces choose one of the strategies below.

a) `sscanf()` to isolate name and age

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, inp)) {
    char name[30];
    int age;
    if (sscanf(line, "%29s%d", name, &age) != 2) /* error, bad line */;
    // ...
}
```

b) `strrchr()` to find the last space, then string manipulation to extract name and age.

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, inp)) {
    char name[30];
    int age;
    char *space = strrchr(line, ' ');
    if (!space) /* error, bad line */;
    if (space - line >= 30) /* error, name too long */;
    sprintf(name, "%.*s", space - line, line);
    age = strtol(space, NULL, 10); // needs error checking
    // ...
}
```

strategy b) on https://ideone.com/ZOLie9

Comment: Thanks for the useful insight, this makes much more sense. So if I understood you correctly, I would use `strrch()` if I had a name _and_ a surname?

Comment: yes, with `strrchr()` you can easily isolate things like `"Foo Bar 42"`.